# How to block my app from run in tablets?

Tags: android, tablet

I dont want my app run in tablets. Is ther any way to do that? I think is something I have to do in the manisfest file but I dont now what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) tag in the manifest if you wish to limit your app to a specific screen size.

Note that the "proper" way of handling big screens such as tablets is adding support for multiple screens (instead of blocking them), see for example the article linked above:

> Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to
>   Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable [support for multiple
>   screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen
>   sizes and densities.